# Getting loss of precision error while initializing a character array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm building a program where I have to scan in a document word by word, parse those words to remove illegal characters, and then assign each word to a hash map. To do this, I'm adding each letter in the word to a character arraylist, then converting that arraylist to an array using an enhanced for loop, then converting that array into a String. The problem is, whenever I try to initialize the character array using the size of my array list as it's size, it throws a Possible Loss of Precision error and seems to want me to enter the value as a character rather than in integer. How can I fix this problem and get my array to work? Please help!

```
  while ( in .hasNext()) {
    String input = in .next();
    Scanner characterizer = new Scanner(input);
    characterizer.useDelimiter("");
    int counter = 0;

    ArrayList < Character > placeHolder = new ArrayList < Character > ();

    while (counter < input.length()) {
        char character = characterizer.next().charAt(counter);
        if (character != '(' && character != ')' && character != '.' && character != '-' && character != '$' && character != '?' & character != '!' && character != ';' && character != ':' && character != '"' && character != '&' && character != '#' && character != '*') {
            placeHolder.add(character);
        }
        counter++;
    }
    final int LENGTH = placeHolder.size();
    char[] word = new char[] {
        LENGTH
    };
    //this code will used the enhanced for loop to copy the contents of placeHolder into word and then convert it to a string
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the char array the wrong way.

```
char[] word = new char[LENGTH];
```

The curly braces are for the content of the array.

Comment: In the sample program, `word` is being initialized as a length 1 array whose only element is `LENGTH`, which would have to be converted to `char`.

Comment: Doh! I knew it was a stupid mistake like that. Thanks for helping a newbie!